# PHP getting records from SQL server using Sqlsrv_query

Tags: php, sql-server, sqlsrv

I have a database table with this name `dbo.[DATABASE$Employee]` and I would like to fetch records from the table but I get an error message

> Notice: Undefined variable: Employee in C:\xampp\htdocs\kekportal\test1.php on line 24
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Employee in C:\xampp\htdocs\kekportal\test1.php on line 28
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: Employee in C:\xampp\htdocs\kekportal\test1.php on line 28

My code:

```
$pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv: Server=U4BUO1D;Database=AmanfoHR","**","**");
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT
dbo.[DATABASE$Employee].No_ AS empID,
dbo.[DATABASEG$Employee].[First Name] AS fname
FROM
dbo.[DATABASE$Employee]");
$stmt->execute(); 
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    echo $row['fname'];
}
```

Comment: It might be better to use PDO

Comment: $pdo = new PDO("sqlsrv: Server=SERV;Database=DB","**","**");
$sql = 'SELECT
dbo.[DATABASE$Employee].No_ AS empID,
dbo.[DATABASE$Employee].[First Name] AS fname,


FROM
dbo.[DATABASE$Employee]';
$q = $pdo->query($sql);
$q->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
 
 
?>
<?php while ($row=$q->fetch()):?>
<?php echo $row['fname'];?>
<?php endwhile ; ?>
i hade error "Fatal error: Call to a member function setFetchMode() on a non-object in C:\xampp\htdocs\kekportal\test1.php on line 30"

Comment: Please edit your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that prepare statement takes `$Employee` as variable and this variable is not defined. Change your query part:

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT
e.No_ AS empID,
e.[First Name] AS fname
FROM
dbo.[DATABASE"."$"."Employee] e");
```

Also you can use another code to work with SQL Server.

```
$serverName = "U4BUO1D";
$connectionInfo = array("Database"=>"AmanfoHR", "UID"=>"userName", "PWD"=>"password");
$conn = sqlsrv_connect( $serverName, $connectionInfo);

$tsql = "
SELECT  No_ AS empID,
        [First Name] AS fname
FROM dbo.[DATABASE"."$"."Employee];";

$stmt = sqlsrv_query( $conn, $tsql);

if( $stmt === false ) {
    echo "Error in executing query.</br>";
    die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
}

while ($obj = sqlsrv_fetch_array($stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $obj['fname'];
}

sqlsrv_free_stmt($stmt);
sqlsrv_close($conn);
```

You need this two extensions to be enabled in php.ini:

```
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv.dll
extension=php_sqlsrv.dll
```